# Help with SPI routing for a display

Tags: spi, display, routing, teensy

I’m designing my first PCB and got weird SPI issues after my second revision of the PCB layout. I did a few small changes for the SPI routing in the second revision but nothing that I thought would affect the SPI bus.

The only components I have mounted on my PCB when testing the SPI bus and the display is the Teensy 4 micro controller, 20 pin display connector and the cable to the display.

On my first version of the PCB, the display works flawless and are stable, I've been running it for days. On my second revision I needed to change the SPI routing to make space for new components and after this modification the SPI bus and display are very unstable and the display fades out to black or some other weird color pattern, sometimes after a few seconds and sometimes after some minutes.

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the SCK signal, because I soldered a cable from the SCK pin on the Teensy to the display connector and it works much better, far from perfect but better, I get some flickering on the display.

I’m running the SPI bus on 30MHz but have tried to go down to 24MHz but get the same behavior.

Anyone have any tips on how best to do SPI routing?

Display pin layout:

- 1 VDD +3.2V
- 2 GND
- 3 SCK
- 4 MISO
- 5 MOSI
- 6 CS
- 8 PD

**First version where the SPI bus and display works great**
[image]

**Second version where the display is unstable**
[image]

**Soldering SCK**
[image]

**SPI schematics for the display**
[image]

Comment: What does the relationship between SCK and MOSI look like on a scope? If slowing things down didn't fix it, seems like SCK is slower on the new layout (more loading?) and it's affecting the MOSI-to-SCK hold time. Try loading MOSI a bit. Maybe also try terminating the SCK and MOSI signals with series RC at the display side.

Comment: Pin 7 seems to be unconnected, but pin 8 is. Are you sure about the pinout? I also don't see a single bypass capacitor on the board, are you sure it works without? The power tracks are awfully narrow, and the ground plane is not very solid. It looks like 30 MHz or 24 MHz going off-board to another PCB via wiring that does not provide good grounding and shielding from crosstalk just too high.

Comment: Display datasheet is where?

Comment: Schematics, please.  Always provide schematics, otherwise we cannot know your intentions on the PCB.

Comment: @Justme pin 7 is not used, neither on the first nor the second version of my PCB. I don't have any bypass capacitor on the first version either but there it works well. Pin 1 is 3.3v logic and pin 17 is +5V powering the display, I used the same track size on the first version as on the second, but maybe I had a better grounding in the first version.

Comment: @Kalle OK, but you said pin 7 is used. Please edit the question so that the PCB and description about it matches. Also post the schematics; it is terrible to try to reverse-engineer the PCB to figure out what might be wrong in the schematics.

Comment: If the digital circuit is working flawless without bypass caps you got lucky! This is highly dependant on layout, if it works at all.

Comment: @Justme sorry, my mistake, the markdown syntax did make my number 8 to 7, I have updated the post with the schematics for the display and SPI connection.

Comment: @brhans datasheet is here, https://riverdi.com/docs/datasheets/eve-3/eve-3-43/ But as I wrote in my post, the first version of PCB works great.

Comment: An oscilloscope would be a really good investment for you. It's almost impossible to do much serious electronics stuff without one. Acceptable ones can be found in the $200-$300 range. If you already have one, then post the traces from it.

Comment: Are you certain that your Teensy's SPI port is configured for Mode-0?

Comment: The imxrt1062 gpio can be set to various drive levels. If you have crosstalk issues, then you can choose a lower drive level. The speed of this device can catch the unwary - it can easily toggle the gpio at 200 MHz with high edge rates.

Comment: Another vote for providing scope captures, please provide waveforms of the SPI lines for both layouts.  If you're going to electronics without a scope, you really needto follow "best practices" to have a reasonable chance of things working.  Put a bypass cap close each power pin with as short a path to ground as possible.  As a guess, you might be getting cross/talk interference.  You could try routing a GND trace between the various SPI lines.